# Missing Create Command Line Launcher in WebStorm

Tags: macos, command-line, terminal, webstorm

## Missing Create Command Line Launcher... in WebStorm on MacOS.

I cannot find a solution anywhere on how to fix this so I decided to post this here for anyone else having this issue.

If you're using Toolbox you can go to

#### 1) Toolbox > settings > shell script location.

#### 2) Type in the location/path

#### 3) click on something else (for some reason it does not save it at all unless you do that).

#### 4) Toolbox > WebStorm > settings > enable shell scripts generation

#### 5) name it something like webstorm (some like wstorm or ws but whatever works for you)

After that is done go to your terminal and enter

```
$ alias ws="~/webstorm "
```

*replace `ws` with whatever you want your shortcut to be and `webstorm` with whatever you named the shell script in the toolbox part.

Then you should be able to use `ws` to open WebStorm from command line.

Some examples:

```
$ ws .  // opens WebStorm with current directory
$ ws ~/path/to/directoryYouWantToOpen   // kind of self explanatory
$ ws    // just opens it up and then it's up to you to use it wisely
```

Hope this helps someone else. I spent too long trying to find a solution and had to piece this together from some closed issues users had opened up with jetbrains.

Comment: I don't usually post in stackoverflow so I wasn't sure if there was a better way to share this with people.  I was really annoyed that I couldn't find an answer so I just wanted to hopefully help someone else with this annoyance.  I don't have enough reputation since I don't post that often so I couldn't just answer it on someone else's question.

Comment: Just posting this because you were unsure of a better way to share this with people, otherwise I wouldn't just post a "+1 Thanks" comment, so in this case: +1 Thanks